# How to extract matrixL() and matrixU() when using Eigen::CholmodSupernodalLLT?

Tags: c++, eigen

I'm trying to use `Eigen::CholmodSupernodalLLT` for Cholesky decomposition, however, it seems that I could not get `matrixL()` and `matrixU()`. How can I extract `matrixL()` and `matrixU()` from `Eigen::CholmodSupernodalLLT` for future use?

Comment: I have the same question. On MATLAB using CHOLMOD the function `ldlchol` outputs the actual decomposition so I was wondering why the `matrixL()` method was not working in Eigen. Did you find an answer eventually?

Comment: @mkln - Are you interested in Eigen or Matlab?
I have added an answer (for the negative!) about Eigen, as asked in the OP.

Comment: Eigen. Basically the idea is to reproduce Matlab's `ldlchol`, considering that Matlab also uses Cholmod under the hood from what I understand. 
It's also kind of counterintuitive that the name suggests LLT but there's no way to extract L itself.

Answer (score 1):

A partial answer to integrate what others have said.

Consider *Y ~ MultivariateNormal(0, A)*. One may want to (1) evaluate the (log-)likelihood (a multivariate normal density), (2) sample from such density.

For (1), it is necessary to solve *Ax = b* where *A* is symmetric positive-definite, and compute its log-determinant. (2) requires *L* such that *A = L * L.transpose()* since *Y ~ MultivariateNormal(0, A)* can be found as *Y = L u* where *u ~ MultivariateNormal(0, I)*.

A Cholesky LLT or LDLT decomposition is useful because `chol(A)` can be used for both purposes. Solving `Ax=b` is easy given the decomposition, andthe (log)determinant can be easily derived from the (sum)product of the (log-)components of `D` or the diagonal of `L`. By definition *L* can then be used for sampling.

So, in `Eigen` one can use:

- `Eigen::SimplicialLDLT solver(A)` (or `Eigen::SimplicialLLT`), when `solver.solve(b)` and calculate the determinant using `solver.vectorD().diag()`. Useful because if `A` is a covariance matrix, then `solver` can be used for likelihood evaluations, and `matrixL()` for sampling.
- `Eigen::CholmodDecomposition` does not give access to `matrixL()` or `vectorD()` but exposes `.logDeterminant()` to achieve the (1) goal but not (2).
- `Eigen::PardisoLDLT` does not give access to `matrixL()` or `vectorD()` and does not expose a way to get the determinant.

In some applications, step (2) - sampling - can be done at a later stage so `Eigen::CholmodDecomposition` is enough. At least in my configuration, `Eigen::CholmodDecomposition` works 2 to 5 times faster than `Eigen::SimplicialLDLT` (I guess because of the permutations done under the hood to facilitate parallelization)

Example: in Bayesian spatial Gaussian process regression, the spatial random effects can be integrated out and do not need to be sampled. So MCMC can proceed swiftly with `Eigen::CholmodDecomposition` to achieve convergence for the uknown parameters. The spatial random effects can then be recovered in parallel using `Eigen::SimplicialLDLT`. Typically this is only a small part of the computations but having `matrixL()` directly from `CholmodDecomposition` would simplify them a bit.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot do this using the given class. The class you are referencing is equotation solver (which indeed uses cholesky decomposition). To decompose your matrix you should rather use [`Eigen::LLT`](https://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox/classEigen_1_1LLT.html). Code example from their website:

```
MatrixXd A(3,3);
A << 4,-1,2, -1,6,0, 2,0,5;
LLT<MatrixXd> lltOfA(A);
MatrixXd L = lltOfA.matrixL(); 
MatrixXd U = lltOfA.matrixU();
```

Comment: Yes, and for sparse matrices one can use Eigen::SimplicialLDLT. I'm aware of that, however (1) Cholmod (or Pardiso) deals with sparse matrices (2) it is much faster than Eigen::SimplicialLDLT.

Answer (score 0):

As reported [somewhere else](https://forum.kde.org/viewtopic.php?f=74&t=127824), e.g., it cannot be done easily.
I am copying a possible recommendation (answered by Gael Guennebaud himself), even if somewhat old:

> If you really need access to the factor to do your own cooking, then
>   better use the built-in `SimplicialL{D}LT<>` class. Extracting the
>   factors from the supernodal internal represations of Cholmod/Pardiso
>   is indeed not straightforward and very rarely needed. We have to
>   check, but if Cholmod/Pardiso provide routines to manipulate the
>   factors, like applying it to a vector, then we could let
>   `matrix{L,U}()` return a pseudo expression wrapping these routines.

Developing code for extracting this is likely beyond SO, and probably a topic for [a feature request](http://eigen.tuxfamily.org/bz/).

Of course, the solution with `LLT` is at hand (but not the topic of the OP).

Comment: Yes unfortunately there's a huge penalty in using `SimplicialLDLT` in my application. in the end I found workarounds (especially because `CholmodDecomposition` still offers `logDeterminant()`) but it would be much cleaner if I could just extract L.

Comment: @mkln - It may be interesting that you post that as an answer.